# Is IDA* the same as IDS using heuristic function?

Tags: algorithm

I have been studying path finding algorithms.
In class our professor has asked us to develop, BFS and IDS.

So I did that, and my question is the following.
So A* is basically the same as BFS using a heuristic function.
So is IDA* the same as IDS with heuristic function too?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance: what is IDS and IDA* standing for?

Comment: Iterative deepening search (IDS)
Iterative deepening A* (IDA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each iteration of either IDA* or IDS is just running A* or BFS (respectively) with a larger depth limit, then the answer would be "yes".

Comment: Thanks, that was a perfect answer. If I may, what would be the major advantages using IDA* over A* ?

Comment: The same as IDS over BFS :)